# Doctrine 2 - One-to-Many unidirectional

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

A couple questions regarding creating a One-to-Many unidirectional relationship in Doctrine 2:

1. Is a join table necessary?
2. The [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) say "look at this example," but all I see is the generated schema.  Anyone mind whipping up a quick example so I can get the annotations correct?

Comment: can you try without the @JoinTable annotation and report if it is working please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the 2.0.x version of the documentation. Check [this one](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table). You will have the example.

So yes, you can avoid the annotation in one of the two classes.

Comment: You can make a one-to-many relationship without using a join table

Comment: why does the example for OnetoMany unidirectional show a ManyToMany?

Comment: @Scott
While this would be the correct answer, some further explanation should be added to explain the ManyToMany.
One of the tables should hold the id of the row for the other table.
But in a one to many, we only have one row and can't assign all the ids.
So we create a ManyToMany which creates another table to hold this mapping for us. Now to lock the OneToMany concept we create a unique index on the inverseJoinColumns of the new table.

Answer (score 2):

This demonstrates a one-to-many relationship, whereby a User can have many Reports, and one Report can only belong to one User.

```
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Report", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $reports;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reports = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addReport(\Namespace\To\Report $report)
    {
        $this->report[] = $report;
    }

    public function getReports()
    {
        return $this->reports;
    }
}
```

and

```
class Report
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="reports")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    public function setUser(\Namespace\To\User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

In this instance, to create a Report and associate it with a User, we would:

```
// create a User (or find an existing one)
$user = new User();
// create the Report
$report = new Report();
// add the User to the Report
$report->setUser($user);
// then persist it, etc ...
```

Comment: He asks for an unidirectional association. Plus, if I remember well, Doctrine will only check the owning side (Report::user), so your 2nd snippet will not work.

Comment: According to Doctrine documentation a one-to-many relationship must be bidirectional, unless you use a join table. So this gives an alternative to a join table, as requested by the OP. However, I was not aware that add->report() cannot be called. It seems strange that Symfony generates these methods if that is the case...

Comment: Ok I did not understand the subject well. I was thinking about a join table in the DBMS. If he talks about the annotation, so, yes, he will need it, but again I'm not sure of that, I need to give it a try. -- addReport can be called but I think it will throw an exception saying that Doctrine found a new entity without auto persist or it will not see it. It is just because doctrine only use owning side of the association and User::report is the inverse side.

Comment: If you want me to remove the -1 just edit your answer (just a little :D) (so constraint. Dont change anything, just add something)

Comment: Have removed the final snippet. If there are other edits required please update, I'd be happy to learn

Answer (score 0):

Nope it is not. Try this:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bars = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\AwesomeBundle\Entity\Bar", mappedBy="foo")
     */
    protected $bars;
}

class Bar
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\AwesomeBundle\Entity\Foo", inversedBy="bars")
     */
    protected $foo;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid my `Bars` from having to know about `Foo` if at all possible.  If it's not, so be it, but I'm hoping for a way to make that happen

Comment: Well I think you can leave out the annotation there, but then the relation won't be unidirectional if I am correct. In case you don't want this because of lose coupling between bundles, have a look at [resolve_target_entities](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)

Answer (score 0):

This works well with Doctrine 2 + Zend Framework 2.5 while fetching one-to-many
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

In my case i had to retrieve Products with their Documents (each Product minimum 5 Documents)

The ArrayCollection does it pretty well itself.

In viewer you have only to foreach the object Product and then once again foreach $product->getDoc() thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but this is how I do it:

```xml
<entity name="User" table="users">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>

    <one-to-many field="children" target-entity="User" mapped-by="father">
    </one-to-many> 

    <many-to-one field="father" target-entity="User" inversed-by="children">
        <!-- without this row it doesn't work -->
        <join-column name="id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </many-to-one>
</entity>
```